# Scroll tableview cell directly beneath the navigation bar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a tableview. On tap, a cell expands into a form, and I would like the cell to scroll up to start right below the navigation bar. How do I achieve this?

**Here's the starting state:**
[image: Starting state]

**Currently, after tap:**
[image: Current behavior]

**And here's what I want:**
[image: Desired behavior]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Perform cell change height code here
    // ...

    // After that scroll to this cell
    CGFloat sectionHeaderHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
    CGRect cellFrame = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, cellFrame.origin.y - sectionHeaderHeight) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Yes, like Vitaly said, you'll need a solution like that. -setContentOffset part is crucial.

Comment: This kind of works, but to bring a cell at the end to the top you need to add a contentInset, which you probably want to remove after you're done with the cell being at the top.

Comment: @StefanKendall you right, there is 2 ways to achieve this  - add bottom content inset, as you say,  or check is cell's frame at the end of table content size and correct content offset appropriately

Answer (score 1):

`scrollToRowAtIndexPath...` or `scrollToNearestSelectedRow...` both take "scroll position" arguments which allow the selection to go to the top, middle or bottom of the table view. That should give you what you want.

Comment: scrollToRow puts the cell beneath the navigation bar.

Comment: Oh, even with the insets on the scroll view adjusted? Does it do that when you're not also resizing the cell? Sounds like a bug.